# Run jquery script on browser window view

Tags: jquery, load

i'm learning jquery, trying to run this jquery script on browser window view. Means script will run, when `class="load-delay"` has browser window view by scroll browser. Actually this script load images after 7 second.

jquery script:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.load-delay').each(function () {
      var imagex = $(this);
      var imgOriginal = imagex.data('original');
      $(imagex).attr('src', imgOriginal);
    });
  }, 7000);
```

Now It's load image after 7 second but I want to load on Window View

HTML:

```
<h1>It Load Image after 7 second not on Window View</h1>
<img class="load-delay" src="http://i.imgur.com/7ZMlu3C.gif" data-original="http://oi42.tinypic.com/9sqmaf.jpg"/>
```

Problem Fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/amf7ca4f/4/

My Question is how to load it on window view `window method` when scroll browser. Load img only when they are scrolled in to view, without LayLoad plugin.

I'm hoping someone could give me a couple suggestions as what to try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want the images to be loaded when they are scrolled in to view?

Comment: If the comment above is what you want. then get this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload. the term is called lazy loading.

Comment: Yes load img only when they are scrolled in to view:)

Comment: i don't want Lay Load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Lets see if we can get this right. We need to scroll to an image and then display it upon reaching the port view.

What if you try something like this? check to see if the user scrolled, then check the bottom view position and compare to the top position of the image. you can then load the image if the bottom view height is >= to that of the image top position.

```
var $w = $(window); 
   $w.scroll(function() {

    var bottom_edge_y = $w.scrollTop()  + $w.height();

    //image class = .load-delay
    var position = $(".load-delay").position();
    if(bottom_edge_y >= position.top)
    {
         //alert("window: " + bottom_edge_y + "image: " + position.top );
        $(".load-delay").attr("src", "http://oi42.tinypic.com/9sqmaf.jpg");
        $(this).off();
    }
});
```

Edit: done, this will show the image upon scrolling to it.

And this here is if you want to show your image when scrolled+7 seconds:

```
var $w = $( window );

$w.scroll(function() {
    var $w = $(window);
    var bottom_edge_y = $w.scrollTop()  + $w.height();
    var position = $(".load-delay").position();
    if(bottom_edge_y >= position.top)
    {
        //alert("window: " + bottom_edge_y + "image: " + position.top );

        setTimeout(function () {
    $('.load-delay').each(function () {
      var imagex = $(this);
      var imgOriginal = imagex.data('original');
      $(imagex).attr('src', imgOriginal);
    });
  }, 7000);

        $(this).off();

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi is this support IE 8 ?

Comment: I lack a device with IE 8. so the short answer is "I don't know".  I have tested with: chrome, IE 11. FF, and safari. My suggestion is get a computer wit IE 8 and try it out.

Comment: I have no any Smart Phone Device 480Px, so are you please tell me that Is it compatible on Small Screen 480Px or 768px....